# Illegal instruction: mint run SwiftGen/SwiftGen@6.5.0

Tags: ios, swift, swiftgen

Running into issues on my machine running mint w/ swiftgen

```
20105 Illegal instruction: 4  mint run SwiftGen/SwiftGen@6.5.0 swiftgen config run --config UI/SupportingFiles/swiftgen.yml
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I'm using mint version: 0.17.1 installed via brew

Any ideas?

Comment: Am seeing the same. Did you figure this out?